# Date Calender Starting Date of Field B should be equals to or advanced from the Ending Date of Field A

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have created a form using webfrom module. The form contains Arrival Date and Leaving Date. I want Leaving date should either be same as Arrival date or higher than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module

> This module adds an extra tab to each webform node, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your webform components.

OR in other case, write custom code, Use `hook_form_alter()` to apply custom validation

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    print $form_id;

    if($form_id=='webform_client_form_1') //Change webform id according to you webformid
    {
        $form['#validate'][]='mymodule_form_validate';
        return $form;
    }
}

function mymodule_form_validate($form,&$form_state)
{
    $phoneval=$form_state['values']['submitted']['phone'];//where "phone" is field name of webform phone field
if($phoneval=='')
{
form_set_error('phone','Please fill the form field');
}
/** THEN USE REGULAR EXPreSSION TO VALIDATE IT  
In above example i have check if phonefield is empty or not
**/

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, let me check if using validation module we can validate if leaving date is advanced than arrival date